# Why calling a public static method from another class is not working in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 2.2.6, I found the code to cast stdClass to another class and I put it in Class_cast_helper and make the cast method to be public static.

```
class Class_cast_helper {

    /**
     *
     * This method allows to cast stdClass to $className
     * @param unknown $instance
     * @param unknown $className
     */
    public static function objectToObject($instance, $className) {
        return unserialize(sprintf(
                'O:%d:"%s"%s',
                strlen($className),
                $className,
                strstr(strstr(serialize($instance), '"'), ':')
                ));
    }

}
```

But when I call this method by

```
$newObj = Class_cast_helper::objectToObject($obj, "Event");
```

It doesn't work.

If I directly put that method in the class (MY_CI_Controller) where it is called

```
class MY_CI_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function test(){
        $newObj = Class_cast_helper::objectToObject($obj, "Event"); // not work
        $newObj = MY_CI_Controller::objectToObject($obj, "Event"); // works
        $newObj = $this->objectToObject($obj, "Event"); // works
    }

    public static function objectToObject($instance, $className) {
        return unserialize(sprintf(
                'O:%d:"%s"%s',
                strlen($className),
                $className,
                strstr(strstr(serialize($instance), '"'), ':')
                ));
    }
}
```

They both work.

Why that method can't be put outside the caller class?

Comment: @Uchiha, you mean if  MY_CI_Controller extends CI_Controller?

Comment: @Uchiha, please see my updated post, I put more details there, it does extend CI_Controller.

Comment: What do you mean - does not work. Does it produce any errors ?

Comment: @OlegLiski, the objectToObject in that Class_cast_helper is not even called.

Comment: what does `var_dump(\class_exists('Class_cast_helper'));` say?

Comment: @xmike, it says

<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <small>/home/seaguest/Git/EventPlanner/application/controllers/event_registration_manager.php:70:</small>
    <small>boolean</small>
    <font color='#75507b'>false</font>
</pre>

Comment: that means your class is not loaded properly (<font color='#75507b'> **false** </font>) . you have to load it somehow (hardcodingly or via autoloader)

Comment: @xmike, great, thanks, I solved my problems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is like xmike said, the Class_cast_helper class is not loaded.

I moved that class under library folder and load it before using it,

```
$this->load->library('Class_cast_helper');
```

this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to create a extended controller.

application/core/MY_Controller.php

```
<?php 

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();

     $this->load->helper('cast'); // load the helper

     // Then you can access function 

     // Just examples
     $this->test();
  }

  public function test(){
    $newObj = $this->cast->objectToObject($obj, "Event");
    $newObj = MY_Controller::objectToObject($obj, "Event");
 }


}
```

The on the controller you need to extend it

Filename: example.php

```
<?php

class Example extends MY_Controller {

public function index() {

}

}
```

When you need to use helper make sure your file name of helper

application/helpers/cast_helper.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

public static function objectToObject($instance, $className) {
    return unserialize(sprintf(
                'O:%d:"%s"%s',
                strlen($className),
                $className,
                strstr(strstr(serialize($instance), '"'), ':')
                ));
}
```